# Language Selector Cookie

Tags: javascript, php

my code is not working. its purpose is to check if a previous cookie has been set for the language. if not it creates a cookie to store the language selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var languageSet = getCookie("setLanguage");
    if (languageSet != "" || languageSet != null) {
        return null;
    } else {
            jQuery.fancybox("#selectFlagDiv");
            setCookie("setLanguage", setLanguage, 365);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to check if the cookie is set?

Comment: no the cookie is not being set.

Comment: Do you get any warnings or error messages in the Javascript console? If so, please could you post them? You're missing a closing `script` tag; is that a copy-paste mistake, or is it missing in your code?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Your checkCookie logic is wrong.

```
function checkCookie() {
    // try and find the cookie or return empty string
    var languageSet = getCookie("setLanguage");
    // if languageSet is not the empty string then the cookie did exist 
    if (languageSet != "") {
    alert('found the cookie'+ languageSet);
        return null;
    } else {
     // otherwise set the cookie to the default value
            jQuery.fancybox("#selectFlagDiv");
            setCookie("setLanguage", 'default cookie value here', 365);
        }
}
```